# Docker on separate Ubuntu-based VMs with the same docker0 IP, how to connect them using overlay network?

Tags: docker, containers

I have set up two separate Ubuntu-based virtual machines (VMs) and installed Docker on both of them. Interestingly, both VMs have the same docker0 IP address, but their host IPs are different.

Now, when I create a container on each VM, both containers end up with the same IP address. My primary objective is to connect these containers using an overlay network.

I created two containers on different VMs and was trying to set up an overlay network to connect these containers.
But interesting thing is that i observe both have same docker0 and containers ip.

How can i connect both docker containers to communicate on a overlay network?

Comment: See [Get started with multi-host networking](https://gdevillele.github.io/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-overlay/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read more articles and found that these behavior is common.This is because Docker uses a bridge network on each host to provide networking capabilities for containers on that host, and by default, these bridge networks have the same subnet (usually 172.17.0.0/16).
and by following few articles i was able to connect both container using swarm service also was able to create a kubernetes cluster.

Please consider it as closed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).